# Can you check if clicking on an element does something? Like take you to another page?

Tags: javascript, click, puppeteer

I am running a test with puppeteer and i try to click on an element that would take me on another page. But the element loads before the click action on it would do something.

```
await page.waitFor(element);
await page.click(element);
```

In this case the click does not do anything. I would like to know if i can do something like this:

```
await page.waitFor(element);
await page.waitForFunction((selector) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    const { clickActionDoesSomething } = element;
    if (clickActionDoesSomething) {
       return true;
    } 
}, selector);
await page.click(element);
```

I would like to avoid page.waitFor(x miliseconds);

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my problem in the meantime. I used:

```
page.evaluate((selector) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  element.click();
}, selector)
```

It seems that in the page context the element.click() triggeres the click action even if it is not loaded yet. Hope this will help others too.